# Unable to step into stored procedure inside stored procedure - SQL debugging using VS2010 and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010

I'm checking out the SQL Debugger using Visual Studio 2010 (connecting to a SQL 2005 Enterprise Server), and I can successfully debug a stored procedure by going to Server Explorer -> Right clicking on the procedure -> "Step Into Stored Procedure".

However, once I'm in, I can't step into or set any breakpoints inside any subsequent function or stored procedure calls.  See the example below:
`esp_StoredProc` calls `esp_AnotherStoredProc`, but I can't set a breakpoint inside of `esp_AnotherStoredProc` or step into it during my debug session.

Is this a limitation of SQL debugging, or perhaps a limitation of my configuration or how I'm debugging things?

```
esp_StoredProc:

-- do something

-- do something else

-- call esp_AnotherStoredProc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in sql server 2005 this was a limitation of SQL debugging. I could be wrong though.

Comment: i forgot to reply to this, but i was able to connect to a local 2005 instance and it stepped through inner procs just fine.  so, something strange was happening, though i haven't resolved it.